# ASP.net download and save file in user folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, savefiledialog

I am trying to save a file to the user pc but I am not able to do it.
This method gives error since is trying to save the file in C somewhere. I understand it is not approriate. I would like to save the file in the download folder or prompt the user with a file dialog.

```
void SaveReport(Telerik.Reporting.Report report, string fileName)
{
    ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new ReportProcessor();
    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
    instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = report;
    RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);

    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        fs.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
    }
}
```

How can I save the file in the download folder of the user machine or prompt a filedialog to allow the user to choose the destination?

Comment: filestream will write to a file on server and not on the client's machine. Try writing the document bytes to response output stream and a content-disposition http header to response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't force the place the file is downloaded to.

In your code, you shouldn't write to file, but to the [`OutputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.outputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from the response.

```
RenderingResult result = reportProcessor.RenderReport("PDF", instanceReportSource, null);

HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"file.pdf\"");
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(result.DocumentBytes, 0, result.DocumentBytes.Length);
```

Comment: Something different is happening but the file does not get downloaded. It appear in the browser completely messed up.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support. I really appreciate the additional help. It works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Filestream will write to a file on server and not on the client's machine.

Try writing the document bytes to response output stream and a `content-disposition` http header to response.

`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");`

This would prompt user for the file download based on browser setting.

You cannot control which directory file goes in in the client's machine.

Comment: I am trying to use your code. How do I integrate it in my code? Sorry but I am really a beginner self learning.