# Download pdf file on remote Client Machine where my publish site is running

Tags: c#

I had publish my site and access it from remote location , but the when i download the pdf file it get downloaded and saved on server side where i published my code.

```
                    int FOrgCountRows = OrgCountRows;
                    string folderName = @"c:\EStatement\";

                        foreach (DataRow dr in DTAC.Rows)
                        {
                            if (DTAC.Rows[FOrgCountRows - OrgCountRows]["Acc"].ToString() == AccArray[CountAcc].ToString())
                            {
                                DataT.ImportRow(dr);
                                if((FOrgCountRows - OrgCountRows)!=( DTAC.Rows.Count)-1)
                                OrgCountRows--;
                                DTACCount++;
                            }

                            if (DTAC.Rows[FOrgCountRows - OrgCountRows]["Acc"].ToString() != AccArray[CountAcc].ToString())
                            {
                                string fileName = "_" + AccArray[CountAcc] + ".pdf";
                                CountAcc++; 
                                string extension;
                                string encoding;
                                string mimeType;
                                string[] streams;
                                Warning[] warnings;

                                LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
                                report.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/Rpt123.rdlc");
                                ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
                                rds.Name = "DataSet1";
                                rds.Value = DataT;
                                report.DataSources.Add(rds);

                                byte[] mybytes = report.Render("PDF", null, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out streams, out warnings); //for exporting to PDF  

                                if (!System.IO.File.Exists(folderName))
                                {
                                    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(folderName + fileName)) 
                                    {
                                        fs.Write(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("File \"{0}\" already exists.", fileName);
                                    return;
                                }

                                Response.Buffer = true;
                                Response.Clear();
                                Response.ContentType = contentType;
                                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
                                Response.WriteFile(folderName + fileName);
```

-----`string folderName = @"c:\EStatement\";` this is the Target folder.. I want to download the files on client machine on this specified folder.. ANy SOLUTION?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate:

[ASP.net download and save file in user folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24593783/asp-net-download-and-save-file-in-user-folder)

Anyway:

"
Filestream will write to a file on server and not on the client's machine.

Try writing the document bytes to response output stream and a content-disposition http header to response.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
```

"

This would prompt user for the file download based on browser setting.

**You cannot control which directory file goes in in the client's machine.**

Comment: Ok . Let me try this and return back to you. Thank you

Comment: still file gets downloaded on server machine.

Comment: Yah,It works with precise output. Thanks a lot Stefano

Comment: Maybe you can sign it as ANSWER :)